# Using jQuery to read img src and insert img src dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have some code on my page that looks like this:

```
<div class="img-center">
    <img src="img-path.jpg" alt="alt-text" class="feature-image" />
    </div>
```

I am setting up a Print Stylesheet and due to some javascript manipulation of the content (and possibly a bug in firefox) the img prints off center. The solution I am going to do is have the img inserted dynamically into another div that will show when printed but I do not know how to have jQuery read the img div and then copy it into the other div. The code example for the other div would be something like this:

```
<div id="feature-container-print">
   <img src="jQuery inserted copy of above img-path.jpg" alt="alt-text" />
     </div>
```

How is this done? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#feature-container-print img').attr('src',$('.feature-image').attr('src'));`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work:

```
$('.feature-container-print img').attr('src', $('.img-center img').attr('src'));
$('.img-center img').hide();
$('.feature-container-print img').show();
```

Comment: That does work, I do not need the last two scripts as I have that taken care of in CSS. Thanks for your help.